# Is there a way to make an iPhone 5S read an SD micro card?

Tags: iphone, sd-card

I have an old point-and-shoot Lumix DMC-FP8 that I would like to be able to directly connect to my iPhone 5S for editing purposes. I bought a camera USB to lightening connector, but the camera is not supported. I tried putting the SD micro card into an adapter and plugging that into my phone, but it says that the device requires too much power. Do I have any options?

Answer (score 1):

I purchased an eye-fi SD card and it works perfectly...once you download the app and connect via wifi to the card, the images transfer right over, where they can be edited just like all the photos taken from the iphone.

Answer (score 0):

The camera connection kit is only for iPad. There is unfortunately no way to connect a camera or SD card to an iPhone/iPod Touch.

Answer (score 0):

Direct connections like that don't work AFAIK.  I believe you'll have to use an intermediate step, such as a laptop, to transfer the file.